# Code crash with alloc, init

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS application that selects ARC option when the application is firstly created.

I have a question about some coding way that causes some crash.  I do not know why the code crash happens if I declare and set memory allocation for a variable in one code line, and then  assigning real value for that variable in another line.

Thank you for your help.

```
// if I use one line of code as follows, then I do NOT have code crash
TrainingCourse* course = [results objectAtIndex:0]; 


// BUT, if I separate the code line above into the 2 line of codes as follows, I get code crash
TrainingCourse* course = [[TrainingCourse alloc] init];
course = [results objectAtIndex:0]; // crash appears here
```

The full method:

```
-(TrainingCourse*) getTrainingCourseWithId:(NSNumber*)trainingCourseId
{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrainingCourse" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trainingCourseId == %@", trainingCourseId];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // if I use one line of code as follows, then I do NOT see any code crash
    TrainingCourse* course = [results objectAtIndex:0]; 


    // BUT, if I separate the code line above into the 2 line of codes as follows, I get code crash
    // TrainingCourse* course = [[TrainingCourse alloc] init];
    // course = [results objectAtIndex:0]; // crash appears here

    return course;

}
```

Comment: Where in the code is the crash occurring?

Comment: Can you paste the exception that the console throws? Also, is TrainingCurse a NSManagedEntity?

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`.

Comment: @bbum, I'm curious - why shouldn't objective-c methods be prefixed with `get`?

Comment: Because `get` is preserved for methods that return by reference through an argument(s).   In this case, the it should just be `trainingCourseWithId:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) check if results even has an entry:

```
assert(results.count);
```

OR

```
if(results.count) ...
```

---

2) if TrainingCourse is a MOM, you have to init it via `initWithEntity`

Comment: thank you very much.  results.count really returns 1 entry.  The problem was I used "init" method instead of working "initWithEntity" method.

Answer (score 1):

Because `TrainingCourse` inherits from `NSManagedObject`, you can't initialize a `TrainingCourse` variable like you do with a full-fledged Objective-C object using alloc/init. To allocate a new managed object, use NSEntityDescription's class method [+insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001173-BBCJCFFG) instead.

```
TrainingCourse *course = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[[TrainingCourse class] name] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```